# Problem Occurred evaluating project ':app'

Tags: android, flutter, gradle, dart, build.gradle

I've created an app on VS Code using Flutter and have had no issues until I started geting the app ready for build. I started changing the package name from "com.example.careona19" to "com.covid19rsa.app" but then started getting this error:

````
```Launching lib\main.dart on VOG L09 in debug mode...

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* Where:
Build file 'C:\Users\pkirby\development\careona19\android\app\build.gradle' line: 24

* What went wrong:
A problem occurred evaluating project ':app'.
> Plugin with id 'com.covid19rsa.app' not found.

* Try:
Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.

* Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

BUILD FAILED in 1m 16s
Gradle task assembleDebug failed with exit code 1
Exited (sigterm)```
````

Android level build.gradle:

````
```buildscript {
    ext.kotlin_version = '1.3.50'
    repositories {
        google()
        jcenter()
    }

    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.6.1'
        //classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.5.0' - original
        //classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.3.2'
        classpath "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-gradle-plugin:$kotlin_version"
        classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:4.2.0'
    }
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        google()
        jcenter()
    }
}

rootProject.buildDir = '../build'
subprojects {
    project.buildDir = "${rootProject.buildDir}/${project.name}"
}
subprojects {
    project.evaluationDependsOn(':app')
}

task clean(type: Delete) {
    delete rootProject.buildDir
}
```
````

App level build.gradle:

````
```def localProperties = new Properties()
def localPropertiesFile = rootProject.file('local.properties')
if (localPropertiesFile.exists()) {
    localPropertiesFile.withReader('UTF-8') { reader ->
        localProperties.load(reader)
    }
}

def flutterRoot = localProperties.getProperty('flutter.sdk')
if (flutterRoot == null) {
    throw new GradleException("Flutter SDK not found. Define location with flutter.sdk in the local.properties file.")
}

def flutterVersionCode = localProperties.getProperty('flutter.versionCode')
if (flutterVersionCode == null) {
    flutterVersionCode = '1'
}

def flutterVersionName = localProperties.getProperty('flutter.versionName')
if (flutterVersionName == null) {
    flutterVersionName = '1.0'
}

apply plugin: 'com.covid19rsa.app'
apply plugin: 'kotlin-android'
apply from: "$flutterRoot/packages/flutter_tools/gradle/flutter.gradle"
//apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'

def keystoreProperties = new Properties()
   def keystorePropertiesFile = rootProject.file('key.properties')
   if (keystorePropertiesFile.exists()) {
       keystoreProperties.load(new FileInputStream(keystorePropertiesFile))
   }

android {
    compileSdkVersion 28

    sourceSets {
        main.java.srcDirs += 'src/main/kotlin'
    }

    lintOptions {
        disable 'InvalidPackage'
    }

    defaultConfig {
        // TODO: Specify your own unique Application ID (https://developer.android.com/studio/build/application-id.html).
        applicationId "com.covid19rsa.app"
        minSdkVersion 16
        targetSdkVersion 28
        versionCode flutterVersionCode.toInteger()
        versionName flutterVersionName
        testInstrumentationRunner "androidx.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
        multiDexEnabled true
    }

    signingConfigs {
       release {
           keyAlias keystoreProperties['keyAlias']
           keyPassword keystoreProperties['keyPassword']
           storeFile keystoreProperties['storeFile'] ? file(keystoreProperties['storeFile']) : null
           storePassword keystoreProperties['storePassword']
       }
   }
   buildTypes {
       release {
           signingConfig signingConfigs.release
       }
   }
}

flutter {
    source '../..'
}

dependencies {
    implementation "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-jdk7:$kotlin_version"
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-core:16.0.1'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test:runner:1.1.1'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.1.1'
    //implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-analytics:17.2.2'
}
apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
```
````

I've been trying every solution I can find but nothing seems to work. Is there something obvious I'm missing?

Comment: In app level gradle, instead of `apply plugin: 'com.covid19rsa.app'` use `apply plugin: 'com.android.application'`

Comment: @MidhunMP - After updating, I still get an error :  * What went wrong:
A problem occurred evaluating project ':app'.
> Failed to apply plugin [id 'com.android.internal.version-check']
   > Minimum supported Gradle version is 5.6.4. Current version is 5.6.2. If using the gradle wrapper, try editing the distributionUrl in C:\Users\pkirby\development\careona19\android\gradle\wrapper\gradle-wrapper.properties to gradle-5.6.4-all.zip

Comment: Try updating your gradle version

Comment: @MidhunMP - Works perfect now... thank goodness, I was close to tears. Please add your answer in the answer section sothat I can mark it as the correct one. Thank you!

Comment: You are welcome. Happy Coding!!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The issue in this line:

```
apply plugin: 'com.covid19rsa.app'
```

You have to use:

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'
```